# Function calls not working in my page

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-font-api

I made an select menu that works with the google-font-Api. I made to function in JSBIN here is my work http://jsbin.com/ocutuk/18/

But  when i made the copy of my code in a html page its not even loading the font names in page. i tried to make it work but still it is in dead end. This is my html code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>FONT API</title>
  <script>
    function SetFonts(fonts) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < fonts.items.length; i++) {      
    $('#styleFont')
     .append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value", fonts.items[i].family)
     .text(fonts.items[i].family));
    }    
  }

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyB8Ua6XIfe-gqbkE8P3XL4spd0x8Ft7eWo&callback=SetFonts';
  document.body.appendChild(script);


  WebFontConfig = {
google: { families: ['ABeeZee', 'Abel', 'Abril Fatface', 'Aclonica', 'Acme', 'Actor', 'Adamina', 'Advent Pro', 'Aguafina Script', 'Akronim', 'Aladin', 'Aldrich', 'Alegreya', 'Alegreya SC', 'Alex Brush', 'Alfa Slab One', 'Alice', 'Alike', 'Alike Angular', 'Allan', 'Allerta', 'Allerta Stencil', 'Allura', 'Almendra', 'Almendra Display', 'Almendra SC', 'Amarante', 'Amaranth', 'Amatic SC', 'Amethysta', 'Anaheim', 'Andada', 'Andika', 'Angkor', 'Annie Use Your Telescope', 'Anonymous Pro', 'Antic', 'Antic Didone', 'Antic Slab', 'Anton', 'Arapey', 'Arbutus', 'Arbutus Slab', 'Architects Daughter', 'Archivo Black', 'Archivo Narrow', 'Arimo', 'Arizonia', 'Armata', 'Artifika', 'Arvo', 'Asap', 'Asset', 'Astloch', 'Asul', 'Atomic Age', 'Aubrey', 'Audiowide', 'Autour One', 'Average', 'Average Sans', 'Averia Gruesa Libre', 'Averia Libre', 'Averia Sans Libre', 'Averia Serif Libre', 'Bad Script', 'Balthazar', 'Bangers', 'Basic', 'Battambang', 'Baumans', 'Bayon', 'Belgrano', 'Belleza', 'BenchNine', 'Bentham', 'Berkshire Swash', 'Bevan', 'Bigelow Rules', 'Bigshot One', 'Bilbo', 'Bilbo Swash Caps', 'Bitter', 'Black Ops One', 'Bokor', 'Bonbon', 'Boogaloo', 'Bowlby One', 'Bowlby One SC', 'Brawler', 'Bree Serif', 'Bubblegum Sans', 'Bubbler One', 'Buda', 'Buenard', 'Butcherman', 'Butterfly Kids', 'Cabin', 'Cabin Condensed', 'Cabin Sketch', 'Caesar Dressing', 'Cagliostro', 'Calligraffitti', 'Cambo', 'Candal', 'Cantarell', 'Cantata One', 'Cantora One', 'Capriola', 'Cardo', 'Carme', 'Carrois Gothic', 'Carrois Gothic SC', 'Carter One', 'Caudex', 'Cedarville Cursive', 'Ceviche One', 'Changa One', 'Chango', 'Chau Philomene One', 'Chela One', 'Chelsea Market', 'Chenla', 'Cherry Cream Soda', 'Cherry Swash', 'Chewy', 'Chicle', 'Chivo', 'Cinzel', 'Cinzel Decorative', 'Clicker Script', 'Coda', 'Coda Caption', 'Codystar', 'Combo', 'Comfortaa', 'Coming Soon', 'Concert One', 'Condiment', 'Content', 'Contrail One', 'Convergence', 'Cookie', 'Copse', 'Corben', 'Courgette', 'Cousine', 'Coustard', 'Covered By Your Grace', 'Crafty Girls', 'Creepster', 'Crete Round', 'Crimson Text', 'Croissant One', 'Crushed', 'Cuprum', 'Cutive', 'Cutive Mono']}
};
(function() {
var wf = document.createElement('script');
wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
  '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
wf.type = 'text/javascript';
wf.async = 'true';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();


 $("#styleFont").change(function (){
   var id =$('#styleFont option' +':selected').val();  
                            $("#custom_text").css('font-family',id);

   });


  </script>
  <style>
      #custom_text {
  font-family: Arial;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 500px;
     }
      #styleFont {
  width: 100px;
     }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <select id="styleFont">
    </select><br>
    <textarea id="custom_text"></textarea>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can i make it work. Whats the mistake i am making here.

Comment: It works on JS bin just fine. What's the issue?

Comment: When i add this in my html page its not working there

Comment: Do you have it published online somewhere? Maybe there's a conflict in another JS file?

Comment: No i have n't published but these are only the exact codes iam using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your scripts to the bottom of the page. The problem as it is now is that the scripts are running before the DOM has formed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>FONT API</title>

  <style>
      #custom_text {
  font-family: Arial;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 500px;
     }
      #styleFont {
  width: 100px;
     }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <select id="styleFont">
    </select><br>
    <textarea id="custom_text"></textarea>

    <script>
    function SetFonts(fonts) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < fonts.items.length; i++) {      
    $('#styleFont')
     .append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value", fonts.items[i].family)
     .text(fonts.items[i].family));
    }    
  }

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyB8Ua6XIfe-gqbkE8P3XL4spd0x8Ft7eWo&callback=SetFonts';
  document.body.appendChild(script);


  WebFontConfig = {
google: { families: ['ABeeZee', 'Abel', 'Abril Fatface', 'Aclonica', 'Acme', 'Actor', 'Adamina', 'Advent Pro', 'Aguafina Script', 'Akronim', 'Aladin', 'Aldrich', 'Alegreya', 'Alegreya SC', 'Alex Brush', 'Alfa Slab One', 'Alice', 'Alike', 'Alike Angular', 'Allan', 'Allerta', 'Allerta Stencil', 'Allura', 'Almendra', 'Almendra Display', 'Almendra SC', 'Amarante', 'Amaranth', 'Amatic SC', 'Amethysta', 'Anaheim', 'Andada', 'Andika', 'Angkor', 'Annie Use Your Telescope', 'Anonymous Pro', 'Antic', 'Antic Didone', 'Antic Slab', 'Anton', 'Arapey', 'Arbutus', 'Arbutus Slab', 'Architects Daughter', 'Archivo Black', 'Archivo Narrow', 'Arimo', 'Arizonia', 'Armata', 'Artifika', 'Arvo', 'Asap', 'Asset', 'Astloch', 'Asul', 'Atomic Age', 'Aubrey', 'Audiowide', 'Autour One', 'Average', 'Average Sans', 'Averia Gruesa Libre', 'Averia Libre', 'Averia Sans Libre', 'Averia Serif Libre', 'Bad Script', 'Balthazar', 'Bangers', 'Basic', 'Battambang', 'Baumans', 'Bayon', 'Belgrano', 'Belleza', 'BenchNine', 'Bentham', 'Berkshire Swash', 'Bevan', 'Bigelow Rules', 'Bigshot One', 'Bilbo', 'Bilbo Swash Caps', 'Bitter', 'Black Ops One', 'Bokor', 'Bonbon', 'Boogaloo', 'Bowlby One', 'Bowlby One SC', 'Brawler', 'Bree Serif', 'Bubblegum Sans', 'Bubbler One', 'Buda', 'Buenard', 'Butcherman', 'Butterfly Kids', 'Cabin', 'Cabin Condensed', 'Cabin Sketch', 'Caesar Dressing', 'Cagliostro', 'Calligraffitti', 'Cambo', 'Candal', 'Cantarell', 'Cantata One', 'Cantora One', 'Capriola', 'Cardo', 'Carme', 'Carrois Gothic', 'Carrois Gothic SC', 'Carter One', 'Caudex', 'Cedarville Cursive', 'Ceviche One', 'Changa One', 'Chango', 'Chau Philomene One', 'Chela One', 'Chelsea Market', 'Chenla', 'Cherry Cream Soda', 'Cherry Swash', 'Chewy', 'Chicle', 'Chivo', 'Cinzel', 'Cinzel Decorative', 'Clicker Script', 'Coda', 'Coda Caption', 'Codystar', 'Combo', 'Comfortaa', 'Coming Soon', 'Concert One', 'Condiment', 'Content', 'Contrail One', 'Convergence', 'Cookie', 'Copse', 'Corben', 'Courgette', 'Cousine', 'Coustard', 'Covered By Your Grace', 'Crafty Girls', 'Creepster', 'Crete Round', 'Crimson Text', 'Croissant One', 'Crushed', 'Cuprum', 'Cutive', 'Cutive Mono']}
};
(function() {
var wf = document.createElement('script');
wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
  '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
wf.type = 'text/javascript';
wf.async = 'true';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();


 $("#styleFont").change(function (){
   var id =$('#styleFont option' +':selected').val();  
                            $("#custom_text").css('font-family',id);

   });


  </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: +1. Possible solution. Better approach would be to have all code in "ready" handler (`$(function() { /*all the initialization scripts*/});`) or even use some AMD framework like requireJS to run code at appropriate time.

Comment: @ThomasHigginbotham  I tried to load all the font-families in WebFontConfig = {
google: { families: ['ABeeZee', 'Abel'....]}
}; but its only loading a few is there a way to load all

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov how can i add all the fonts in the families option. Any idea to do it in scripts

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason is simple:

You tried to manipulate some DOM elements before it gets fully loaded.

Wrapping your code inside a

```
$(function(){
}
```

would solve the problem.

More specifically, you can change your code to like this:

```
  function SetFonts(fonts) {
  for (var i = 0; i < fonts.items.length; i++) {
  $('#styleFont')
   .append($("<option></option>")
   .attr("value", fonts.items[i].family)
   .text(fonts.items[i].family));
  }
}

$(function(){
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyB8Ua6XIfe-gqbkE8P3XL4spd0x8Ft7eWo&callback=SetFonts';
document.body.appendChild(script);

 // all the rest of your code....
});
```

Comment: I did a mistake to include SetFonts function inside $(function(){...} . with my last edit it should work.